# ASP.NET: How to access a dynamically created control

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, checkbox

I'm creating a bunch of Checkboxes dynamically:

```
CheckBox chkRead = new CheckBox();
chkRead.ID = "chk1";
chkRead.AutoPostBack = true;
chkRead.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

CheckBox chkPost = new CheckBox();
chkRead.ID = "chk2";
chkPost.AutoPostBack = true;
chkPost.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);


 protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;


 }
```

What I want to do is the following:
   When I check the **chkPost** CheckBox I want the **chkRead** CheckBox to be checked as well

In the **CheckBox_CheckedChanged** event I only have access to the CheckBox that was clicked
   but I don't know how to check the other checkbox from that event.

Comment: Did you try `control.FindControl("chk1");`? If you recreated your dynamic checkboxes on postback you should be able to access it...

Comment: @Robert Koritnik Yes I tried that but it returns null. I should mention that the checkboxes are inside a Div control which in turn is inside another ul/li elements.

Comment: ASP.NET FindControl is not recursive. You need to go in-depth for this or call FindControl on the container that chkRead was added to.

Comment: But you do recreate the whole dynamic structure on postback within Init or Load event? **Do you?** And yes Igor you're correct. I just wanted to spark idea... changed *Page* to *control* to make it more unambiguous.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik yes I recreate the dynamic structure in the Init event.

Comment: But did you traverse containers with `FindControl` to get to your checkbox?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Thank you for all the suggestions I think using NamingContainer to find the container where chk resides as Ann L. suggested did the trick, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yes that simplifies traversal because you get to container immediately without traversing the whole page control hierarchy. Great idea yes. I've awarded it... And it also shows that traversal would work just as well but would have a much higher performance penalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from memory, but you could do something like this:

```
protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    CheckBox chkPost = (CheckBox) chk.NamingContainer.FindControl("chk2");
    CheckBox chkRead = (CheckBox) chk.NamingContainer.FindControl("chk1");
    if(chk == chkPost && chk.Checked)
    {  
        chkRead.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you want to do all this in code-behind, after postback.  If you want to do it in javascript, that's a different question.

This also assumes that `chk1` and `chk2` are in the same naming container.  If they aren't, things will get complicated.

Comment: `chkRead` is likely local method variable and not global page variable/property... Hence the question. I expect OP to know that.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik  In fact, you've given me an idea.  Editing again.

Comment: @AnnL. using NamingContainer to find the control where chk resides was genius, thank you Ann that was exactly what I need.

Comment: That's a great idea Ann. I'm glad I was of some help as well... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is your code that creates the checkboxes, you can store their references in a list or dictionary and retrieve them by id when needed.

Comment: I suppose you should mention that dictionary can be page-level local in-memory variable so people won't be putting it in session or any other object-capable cache... :) Then this dictionary would be populated on every page request when creating dynamic controls. Nice and simple. Better (and faster) than control tree traversal. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamically you can add an attribute to the checkboxess you are interested in-- you can then loop over the Page.Controls collection and test that the control you are looping over has that attribute and then you can check, or uncheck it.

some pseudo code:

```
foreach(var control in Page.Controls)
  if(typeof(Control) is CheckBox and ((CheckBox)control).Attributes["myAttr"] != null)
     //check or uncheck it
```

In reading your comment about nested controls-- this might be a bit of a hassle-- I tend to agree with Igor, that you should put the id's in a collection as they are being added dynamically.

Comment: ID is an attribute as well. Why do we need more?

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste code where you are creating these checkboxes? Is it "OnInit" or somewhere else? Are you putting these checkboxes in container, do you store these controls as global variables or create them in method?